# How to change the spacing of values in a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a chunk size in relation to run time with the different chunk sizes on the x-axis being 1000, 10000, 100000, and 1000000. However, when I create the plot using the `plot()` and `axis` commands.

```
plot(chunk, totTime, main="Runtime with Different Chunks", xaxt = "n",ylim = c(4,5),ylab="Runtime (sec)", xlab = "Size of Chunk", type="l") 
axis(side = 1, c(1000,10000,100000,1000000))
```

I get a plot that looks like this.

[image: Plot]

I've tried `axp` in `plot()` and `at` in the `axis` function but it still has the same spacing. So, I wonder if there was a way to change how the graph spaces the data in the plot so the graph will look cleaner.

Comment: Or just add the argument `log = "x"` to your plot command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting to the log scale but labeling your x-axis according to the set values you want (here, `xvalues`). This will put equal spacing between orders of magnitude:

```
# Sample data
totTime <- c(4.4, 4.01, 4.01, 4.8)
chunk <- c(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)

# Values desired on the x-asis
xvalues <- c(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)

# Plot
plot(
  log(chunk), # note the log scale
  totTime,
  main = "Runtime with Different Chunks",
  xaxt = "n",
  ylim = c(4, 5),
  ylab = "Runtime (sec)",
  xlab = "Size of Chunk",
  type = "l"
)

axis(side = 1,
     at = log(xvalues), # note the log scale
     label = xvalues)
```

Output:

[image]